# MySQL Should I frequently update date field even if the value is unchanged?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Upon user's every login the last login date is updated.

```
UPDATE `last_login` SET `date`= CURDATE() WHERE `user_id` = $login
```

If user logs in 10 times in one day, then the `date` field will be updated 10 times with absolutely the same date.

**Question:** Is there any performance benefit if, before updating the `date`, I check if the value in the that field is different from `CURDATE()`, and only in this case update it? 
It will reduce number of unnecessary updates, but will add extra trip to DB for every separate log in.

Comment: in an ideal login audit you should record each login with datetime, just update will give you last time the user logs in but the history audit will not be there.

Comment: In my case the date is enough, because it is needed only to see if a user has logged in within last 6 months, if not then the account is deactivated. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a condition for that

```
  UPDATE `last_login`
  SET `date`= CURDATE()
  WHERE `user_id` = $login
  AND `date` <> CURDATE()       << that one
```

That will update only when its not the same date

> It will reduce number of unnecessary updates, but will add extra trip to DB for every separate log in

No its not an extra trip, you're already making that trip. That adds no significant performance overhead since *supposedly* that `user_id` has to be primary or atleast an index and will return only 1 row for that comparison.

Comment: Well, question is about _benefit_ of doing this. And this query will produce additional comparison. Update/select also depends of index (i.e. if it exists on the field)

Comment: It will produce an extra comparison but it will reduce 10 such data updates per user per day And no an index is not required there as im sure user_id is indexed  (or primary) so it will already be one row which is returned for that comparison

Comment: Its not required to be indexed as long as the `user_id` is

Comment: It's not for selection, but will be for updating (because even if index won't be used on select, it should be re-structured o update).

Comment: `1000` users with `5` logins per day will produce a reduction of `4000` updates per day using this simple condition, hence reducing `120K` monthly updates: hence the *benefit*.

Comment: Hanky: By this: `It will reduce number of unnecessary updates, but will add extra trip to DB for every separate log in`, I meant to run a separate `SELECT` query to fetch the date and compare it, I did not figure out to do a comparison like you proposed. (i'm still learning the stuff). Thanks for the help.